# How can i check additional category exist when mapping this array in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Here, SubCategoryDetail contains Additional Category but SubCategoryDetail may not have an Additional Category. I need to check where the  Additional Category exists then go to the AdditionalCategoryDetail option if not exist then show SubCategoryDetail products when I'm mapping this array.

```
      categoryDetail: [
        {
            id: 0,
            SubCategoryName: "Sewing Section",
            SubCategoryDetail: [
            {
              id: 0,
              AdditionalCategoryName: "Additional Category Name 0",
              AdditionalCategoryDetail: [
              {
                id: 0,
                ProductName: 'Product Name 0',
                ProductImg: "images/AllCategories/SubCategories/3.png",
                Price: '80.00',
                Brand: 'Brand'
              },
              {
                id: 1,
                ProductName: 'Product Name 1',
                ProductImg: "images/AllCategories/SubCategories/4.png",
                Price: '70.00',
                Brand: 'Brand'
              }]
            }]
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            SubCategoryName: "Cutting Section",
            SubCategoryDetail: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    ProductName: 'Product Name 0',
                    ProductImg: "images/AllCategories/SubCategories/2.png",
                    Price: '100.00',
                    Brand: 'Brand'
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    ProductName: 'Product Name 1',
                    ProductImg: "images/AllCategories/SubCategories/2.png",
                    Price: '100.00',
                    Brand: 'Brand'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
         }
       ]
```

Comment: you can check if object contains a key or not like `obj.hasOwnProperty('key')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
results = categoryDetail.map(categories => {
    return categories.SubCategoryDetail.map(category => {
       if (category.hasOwnProperty("AdditionalCategoryDetail")) {
          return category.AdditionalCategoryDetail[0]
       } else {
          return category[0]
       }
     })[0]
 })
```